# Spring 2.5 login not responding even with the correct username/password

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I developed a login mechanism for one of my projects with Spring 2.5 , asegi security 1.0.7 and I used Tomcat 6 as my development server.When I was developing the project everything worked fine and I could successfully log-in.The problem begun when I deployed my application on the production server.From the moment I deployed the application on the production tomcat 6 I could not log-in even with the correct username and password and the most weird of all is that no exception is thrown.I just can't log -in!
here is the application-context.xml of the application:

```
     <bean id="authedicationProvider" class="org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailService"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.htm" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="filterChainProxy"
      class="org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy">
    <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
      <value>
        CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
        PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
        /**=authenticationProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
      class="org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/error.htm" />
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/admin_menu.htm" />
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_acegi_security_check" />

  </bean>
  <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.acegisecurity.vote.RoleVoter"/>
  <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.acegisecurity.vote.UnanimousBased">
      <property name="decisionVoters">
          <list>
              <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
          </list>
      </property>
      <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="true"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
      <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
      <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
      <property name="objectDefinitionSource">
          <value>
              CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
              PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
              /add_article.htm=ROLE_ADMIN
              /add_publication.htm=ROLE_ADMIN
              /admin_menu.htm=ROLE_ADMIN
          </value>
      </bean>
  </property>
  </bean>
  <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager">
      <property name="providers">
          <list>
              <ref bean="authedicationProvider"/>
          </list>
      </property>
  </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailService" class="org.acegisecurity.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
        <property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
            <value>
                SELECT username,password,'true' AS enabled FROM Users where username=?
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
            <value>
                SELECT username,role_name FROM Roles r,Users u WHERE r.user=u.id AND u.username=?
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Am I missing somthing?Any help would be really appreciated!Thank you in advance

Comment: @kafrlust Does the logged in user have ROLE_ADMIN?  The defaultTargetUrl is a page which needs this Authority.  Also, you can get more info by setting log level for acegi to DEBUG

Comment: yes the logged in user has ROLE_ADMIN! It is very weird though that I haven't changed anything and when in my development server works fine and when in the live server it doesn't!

Comment: Does the login http request reach your application, or is is "blocked" by the server?

Comment: Yes the request reaches the server.It acts as if i give wrong username/password even when I give the correct username/password

Comment: Can you check your production database and see if the specified user/role exist?

Comment: Yes it exist and in fact I copy/pasted username/password from the production db in case it was encoding problem or something but nothing changed

Comment: Have you set correctly the user/password in the properties file (or wherever you have to set them) to access to the database in the production environment? I don't mean the login/password of the application but the user/password to access to the database. (Though I think this would result in an error message in the log)

Comment: Yes the username/password are correct!I don't have problem with accessing the data stored in the database! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have `<bean id="authe**d**icationProvider"` in your first line of application file ?

Comment: yes it is!It's been a month and still haven't found the answer!

Comment: @kafr: Shouldn't this be `<bean id="autheticationProvider"` ?
With a `t` and not `d`

Comment: @ oneofthelions believe me there is no effect whether it is with a "nt" or "d".The problem is still there.